# javascript form submission one value should greater than other value x>y

Tags: javascript

my code is not work proprerly

JS:

```
function verify() {
 var x = document.add_form.max_temp.value ;
 var y = document.add_form.min_temp.value == "";
 if (x < y) {
  alert("Sorry, you don't have enough points");return false;
 }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="add_form" action="add_mor_data.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="max_temp" name="max_temp" />
   <input type="text" id="min_temp" name="min_temp" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="search" onClick="return (verify());"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please note the guys here like a bit of detail when it comes to answering questions and you need to show you've put some effort into solving this issue yourself. "my code is not working properly" is not only a lazy question but also doesn't tell us anything. What are you expecting to see? What actually is happening, any errors? that sort of thing. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get the best results, please check the ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in the Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare strings instead of numbers and have to cast it to Integer.

Change your function to:

```
verify = function() {
     var x = document.getElementById("max_temp").value;
     var y = document.getElementById("min_temp").value;
     if (parseInt(x) < parseInt(y)) {
      alert("Sorry, you don't have enough points");
      return false;
     }
    }
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M9gE8/5/)